# How to increase row height in list field dynamically in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am displaying list of data which is coming from web service in list field.If the list item width is with in row width it is ok.But if the text length is more the text displaying in only one line.and last text is disappearing.How to display the large text in multiple lines by increasing row height in list field blackberry.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot  resize the height of list field dynamically

Comment: create a vertical Field Manager,to that Manager add the list of horziontalManager,Check out that

Comment: VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager();for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){HorizontalFieldManager hfm=new HorizontalFieldManager();hfm.add(/**ur data**/)vfm.add(hfm);}this.add(vfm);

Comment: Try with this one..ListField.setRowHeight(index,height) in your drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index,
   int y, int width) {..callback method.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager();
HorizontalFieldManager hfm=new HorizontalFieldManager();
for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
hfm.add(/**ur data**/);
hfm.setMargin(top, right, bottom, left);
vfm.add(hfm);
}
this.add(vfm);
```